# codecademy basics: delete starting numbers. what's wrong with this code?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, break

the function is supposed to repeatedly remove the first element of a list until it finds an odd number or runs out of elements. i did it in a more complicated way than their solution, but still don't understand why it isn't working as well.

their funcion:

```
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
  while (len(lst) > 0 and lst[0] % 2 == 0):
    lst = lst[1:]
  return lst
```

my function:

```
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
  for num in lst:
    if num % 2 == 0:
      lst.remove(num)
    else:
      break
  return lst
```

i expected it to check each number and remove it if it was even, but break otherwise (if it was odd), leaving the rest of the list as it is.

the result was this:

```
print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]))
[8, 11, 15]

print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10]))
[8]
```

why wasn't 8 removed? and why did it still remove 12 (after 11) on the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

The reason the 8 stays in the list is because Python keeps track of the list elements with a counter. Removing elements of a list in a for loop causes unexpected behavior because the list changes but the counter stays the same. That is why the 8 gets skipped.

You can run this code with print statements to check it out for yourself:

```
lst = [4, 8, 10]
for num in lst:
    print(f"Checking num {num}")
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print(f"Removing num: {num}")
        lst.remove(num)
    else:
        print(f"breaking out for num: {num}")
        break
print(lst)
```

That is why the answer they provided uses a while loop and recreated the list each loop. That way everything works as expected.

Comment: ohh, got it! i didn't realise the tracking was done with a counter and removing elements would mess it up. that's why it also didn't break on 11, it just skipped it. thank you!